# Change image backgroud color with python

Tags: python, image, background, opencv

I am trying to change the background color of an image with python and save it as a new image with that background but I can't seem to figure it out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8xFd.jpg)

This is the function i am trying to use

```
import cv2
tolerancia = 10
point = (0, 0)
def floodFill(filename):
    cv2.imread(filename,0)
    cv2.floodFill(img, None, point, (255, 255, 0), (tolerancia,) * 3, (tolerancia,) * 3) # b g r
    cv2.imwrite('./images/fondonuevo.jpg', img)
```

Any clues on how this could work?

Comment: Why have you removed the `import` statements? Why are you opening the image with PIL but saving it with OpenCV - it will swap the red and blue channels.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell , you are right, i have updated the code now, but still doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

1) You didn't actually call your `floodFill()` function

2) You didn't assign the result of reading the file to a variable

3) You opened the image in greyscale but tried to add colour to a greyscale image

---

```
import cv2
tolerancia = 10
point = (0, 0)

def floodFill(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    cv2.floodFill(img, None, point, (255, 255, 0), (tolerancia,) * 3, (tolerancia,) * 3)
    cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',img)

floodFill('bottle.jpg')
```

[image]

Comment: wow thanks so much! The only thing is, is there any way to fine tune the result? i tried playing with "tolerancia" and it improves a little, but its not quite perfect. Any hints?

Comment: Not really. If there is little difference between foreground and background colours, it is hard to separate them - that's why folk use chroma keying... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key